# Linux Mint 21.1, nvidia driver problem

Tags: kernel, apt, drivers, nvidia, cinnamon

I have a problem with the latest linux mint 21.1 with cinnamon environment. The system after installation was fully updated. The problem is that when I want to install the nvidia driver from the driver manager, e.g. version 525 or lower, it writes that:

**Error while installing package: installed nvidia-dkms-525 package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 10**

```
/var/lib/dkms/nvidia/525.60.11/build/make.log

https://pastebin.com/nZc82Ayy
```

The card is rtx 2060 oc. **I have secureboot and tpm enabled as I need windows 11 for my work**. Sudo apt -f install does not do the trick. I changed the kernel to 5.19 and the problem is the same.

**Generally on ubuntu 22.04 distros I have this problem. Once I install some fork ubuntu, or even ubuntu 22.10 original with gnome, there is no problem for nvidia.**

I don't know how to fix it, I'm new to linux.

Comment: Better ask on nvidea's forum, they even have some answers: https://forums.developer.nvidia.com/t/errors-were-encountered-while-processing-dkms/236521/8

Comment: @WhiteOwl Not work :(

Comment: "I want to install the nvidia driver from the **driver** manager" ??? You mean the **package** manager I presume ?

Comment: Yes, driver manager installed in linux mint. Select the version of the nvidia driver you want to install and click apply.

Comment: I have the same problem. Work around: use Linux 5.15.

Comment: I fixed the problem. Install gcc-12 package. Rebuild nvidia-driver, reboot computer.